# How to loop Object.values array?

Tags: javascript, loops, object

How to get single values from object.values array?

I am getting this obj in console.log() // {"item": Array(3)}

```
 {"item": (3) ['21', '14', '12']}
```

and I want to get single  number from object.values // 21 ,14, 12

I am trying this

```
let j = Object.values(data)
  console.log(j)  // [Array(3)]
```

Comment: `j` is an Array ... loop like you would an array, note: your array is an array of strings, an `21 ,14, 12` is NOT a **single number**, it's three numbers

Comment: Well technically, j is an array of arrays that contains a single element (an array of strings).

Comment: Use the key instead of .values(). Like this: data["item"] (or data.item). That will give you the array. If you want a single value: data.item.join(', ');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am not sure what data is present in the variable `data`. Let's assume `j` is an object with item `items` which is an array.

```
let j = {"items" : ['21', '14', '12']};
```

If you want to print each element in the array individually, you can use `forEach`

```
j.items.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```

This will print

```
21
14
12
```

or if you need to print all the elements in a single line without a loop, You can use `join`

```
let result = j.items.join(",");
console.log(result);
```

which will print

```
21,14,12
```

You can replace the `,` with whatever separator you wish to use.

```js
let j = {"items" : ['21', '14', '12']};

console.log("List with loop");
j.items.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});

console.log("List with join");
let result = j.items.join(",");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The code is correct and the anwser is good but to be clear. J is cleary not an array of arrays.. J is an object with a property "items" that contains an array. As said by the OP: *I am getting this obj*

Answer (score 0):

Object.values() function returns all values (of various properties) in an object -- itself in an array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

```js
let data = {"item":['21', '14', '12']}
let j = Object.values(data); //returns object values in an array
j.map((item) => {
if(!Array.isArray(item)){
  console.log(item)
}
else{
item.map(val => console.log(val));
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in my option **map** is better than **forEach**

```
let j = {"items" : ['21', '14', '12']};
j.items.map((num)=>console.log(num));
```

it will print output in console

21

14

12